# What are the minimum requirements for a trip to "Altum Sagittarii Prime"?

Tags: elite-dangerous

### Prologue

One of the optional waypoints, on an expedition I'll be joining soon, is "Altum Sagittarii Prime" (Quemeou YE-A E0). This sits some 2,870 Ly directly "above" Sagittarius A*, offering a rather unique view of the Milky Way galaxy.

I wanna do it, but I'm having a hard time nailing down the exact requirements for reaching that system. "Altum Sagittari" (Nyuena JS-B D342) is a good bit closer Sagittarius A*, and I'm told that requires a minimum range of 33 Ly (or FSD boosts to compensate) to reach.

But, for "Prime", all I've really been told is "bring jumponium".

Without knowing exactly how far I'll need to be able to jump, or how many long-distance (>33 Ly) jumps I'll need to make, there's no way to know whether I'll even need to use FSD boosts - or, if I do, how many supplies I need to bring with me for them.

Can anyone who's been there (or perhaps happens to be in range of it now) confirm what the minimum requirements would be for a trip to Altum Sagittarii Prime?

To make this relatively simple, let's assume I have a ship that can make it to Altum Sagittarii (i.e.: I have at least a 33 Ly jump range). And, since we already know the mission requirements for Altum Sagittarii, let's use that as the starting point.

### Answer Requirements

What I need to know is:

- Minimum number of jumps required, to reach Altum Sagittarii Prime from Altum Sagittarii, which necessarily exceed the mission requirements (33 Ly range) for the trip to Altum Sagittarii.
- Minimum distance for each of those jumps.
- Other obstacles which may affect ship build/supply requirements or route planning for this portion of the trip. (e.g.: Parts of the route without main-sequence stars for refueling. Anything else I've forgotten.)

Comment: FTR: CMDR Alot has helpfully provided a [possible route](http://pastebin.com/CXsWTE8z) using his own Python tools and data from EDSM. So far, it looks like there's three jumps beyond the 33 Ly range - the largest being close to 60 Ly. There's also three T Tauri stars at the end of the route, meaning you need a tank big enough to make at least 7 jumps before refueling. I'll post this as an answer after confirmation in-game.

Comment: very cool research from CMDR Alot. Would love to see this functionality in-game, at least for stars players have visited. Youd think your nav computer would know this stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've finally made it up to Altum Sagittarii Prime and back. The [route](http://pastebin.com/CXsWTE8z) provided to me by CMDR Alot, generated using [EDTS](https://bitbucket.org/Esvandiary/edts), is now confirmed to work.

Alternative routes may still be viable, with different jumponium and/or jump range requirements. However, the limited availability of scoopable stars at the far end of this trip should also be taken into consideration.

These probably aren't the barest-minimum requirements. But if you get to Altum Sagittarii prepared as I describe below, you shouldn't have any trouble making it to Prime and back.

- Jump range: At least 33 Ly, after accounting for intended cargo load and a full fuel tank.
- Fuel tank capacity: Enough for 7 maximum-range jumps.
- Total jumponium materials: Enough for 2 each of Basic, Standard, and Premium injections.

  - 6x Vanadium
  - 4x Germanium
  - 4x Cadmium
  - 8x Niobium
  - 2x Arsenic
  - 2x Yttrium
  - 2x Polonium

Here's some more general information, on what to expect in the round-trip if you're flying with the above configuration.

- Boosted jumps required: 6
- Biggest jump: 59.53 Ly
- Longest drought (jumps without a scoopable star): 6

One-way route detail:

```
Jump #  Dist.   Target              Main Star
=============================================
0       0.00Ly  Nyuena JS-B D342    F
1       31.99Ly Nyuena WQ-B c1-20   K
2       32.94Ly Nyuena JS-B d139    G
3       29.75Ly Nyuena QY-A e490    *T Tauri*
4       29.92Ly Nyuena WG-A c2-21   K
5       28.23Ly Nyuena KD-A d1-138  F
6       28.93Ly Nyuena QY-A e346    *T Tauri*
7       30.81Ly Nyuena JI-A d1-26   *T*
8       30.40Ly Nyuena FC-C d128    A
9       28.82Ly Nyuena LP-C c1-4    G
10      29.38Ly Nyuena GN-A d1-83   K
11      26.61Ly Nyuena CH-C d19     G
12      25.72Ly Nyuena CH-C d17     M
13      27.04Ly Nyuena OD-B e258    *T Tauri*
14      32.89Ly Nyuena AM-C d128    K
15      17.07Ly Nyuena AM-C d79     M
16      32.65Ly Nyuena YQ-C d100    M
17      29.91Ly Nyuena AT-D c1-0    M
18      27.67Ly Nyuena DX-A d1-52   M
19      25.09Ly Nyuena AC-B d1-2    F
20      20.71Ly Nyuena AC-B d1-38   F
21      27.47Ly Nyuena AC-B d1-27   *L*
22      29.04Ly Nyuena DP-A c3-1    K
23      24.04Ly Quemeou NS-U c2-0   M
24      27.00Ly Quemeou EG-Y d39    F
25      20.73Ly Quemeou LX-U c2-0   K
26      20.24Ly Quemeou EG-Y d18    M
27      24.80Ly Quemeou CL-Y d1     F
28      32.59Ly Quemeou CL-Y d10    F
29      27.55Ly Quemeou CL-Y d29    G
30      24.24Ly Quemeou AA-A f25    *T Tauri*
31      25.07Ly Quemeou AQ-Y d15    G
32      31.08Ly Quemeou AQ-Y d7     G
33      28.08Ly Quemeou FW-W d1-6   F
34      28.46Ly Quemeou YE-A e7     G
35      59.53Ly Quemeou AA-A f2     *T Tauri*
36      43.90Ly Quemeou AA-A f22    *T Tauri*
37      37.18Ly Quemeou YE-A e0     *T Tauri*

*Non-Scoopable*
```

*Note: The single-jump distance between Quemeou YE-A e7 (jump 34 on the list) and Altum Sagittarii Prime is only 81.71 Ly. So, a ship with a 41 Ly jump range could make the round trip with just two Premium injections. This also saves the worry of going through so many jumps without an opportunity to refuel.*